# PTIJ: Heads and Tails with Adam HaRishon

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Is the Torah describing a game of heads and tails when speaking about the creation of man? According to [Brachot 61a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.61a?lang=bi), Chava was made from a tail (seemingly Adam's tail). According to [Vayikra Rabbah on Tazria 12:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.12.2?lang=bi&with=Vayikra%20Rabbah&lang2=en), Adam had 2 faces.

Is this an indication that Heaven decided between **heads** and **tails**?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I don't see how this is an "or" question. Why couldn't both parts have been used?

Comment: @Moshe The meforshim bring from the ari that they were both heads and tail. And that is what is meant l'rosh v'loi lzonov, not to stay a tail. I can provide an image of the sefer who brings it.

Answer (score 1):

When Adam was created, God was portending a verse that he would eventually write in the Torah:

וּנְתָֽנְךָ֨ יְהוָ֤ה לְרֹאשׁ֙ וְלֹ֣א לְזָנָ֔ב

When Adam was first created by himself, he went for the head, as God anticipated that he would be a flawless being and would never sin. He would always follow God's commandments and thus always be a "head".

But, then, God realized that this wasn't realistic behavior of man, as he would eventually disobey His commandments, and, sure enough, his wife encouraged him to do that. Thus, he created woman from the tail.

Comment: the ari zl as I wrote says something similar

Comment: @interested I guess that shouldn't surprise me. My name is Daniel and I mentioned something said by a lion!

Comment: you can see it your self here https://mefo.otzar.org/#/t/21106.02136624684/b/173917/p/128/s/235912    If you wade through all 46 of them